# How to filter values in one column of df that are not in another df with same column name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have two Dataframes that have a state column and I need to filter out the states in one Dataframe that is not in the other.

#Code task 32

#Find the states in `state_summary` that are not in `usa_states_sub`

#Hint: set(list1) - set(list2) is an easy way to get items in list1 that are not in list2

`missing_states = set(state_summary.state) - set(usa_states_sub)`

when I do this it only filters out 1 state when there should be 4.

Comment: shouldn't be `.state` in second `set()` - like `set( usa_states_sub.state )` ?

Comment: you should show data so we could test it and see why it doesn't select 4 states. Maybe you have wrong code or you have to convert all names to lowercase. Or some names has spaces which you can't see but they can change result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.in1d()`.

Try this:

```
state_summary = pd.DataFrame(['New York', 'California', 'Texas', 'Massachusetts'], columns=['state'])
usa_states_sub = pd.DataFrame(['California', 'Massachusetts'], columns=['state'])
missing_states = state_summary.loc[np.in1d(state_summary.state, usa_states_sub.state), 'state']
```

Output:

```
print(missing_states)

1       California
3    Massachusetts
Name: state, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to use a list comprehension. Given these are 2  different dataframes, I'll just refer to the column of states as `states`.

```
filter_states=[s for s in state_summary.states if s not in usa_states_sub.states]
```

This will create a list of all the states not present in the second dataframe